# Node Red get configuration node value in Admin UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

It's possible that this is the wrong approach but basically I would like to create a node where one of the dropdowns depends on a config node value.

**config-test.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType('test-config', {
        category: 'config',
        defaults: {
            token: { value: '' }
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="test-config">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-config-input-token"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Token</label>
        <input type="text" id="node-config-input-token" placeholder="Token">
    </div>
</script>
```

**config-test.js**

```
module.exports = function (RED) {
    function TestConfig(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
        this.token = config.token;
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType('test-config', TestConfig);
}
```

So then in the new node I would like to do this:

**test-node.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType('test-node', {
        defaults: {
            token: { value: '', type: 'test-config' },
            node: { value: '' }
        },
        oneditprepare: function () {
            var token = ??????;
            var nodes = $('#node-input-node');

            reloadNodeSelect();

            function reloadNodeSelect() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '--URL--' + token
                    success: function (res) {
                        nodes.html('');
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.obj.length; i++) {
                            nodes.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', res.obj[i]).text(res.obj[i]));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="temp-node">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-input-node"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Node</label>
        <select type="text" id="node-input-node"></select>
    </div>
</script>
```

The case is that there is an API that uses a token and a web request for a list of nodes each with their own individual token the API needs for requests against that particular node. There are also several additional sub items for each node that I would like to list and allow the user to select for the given test-node. The config of each node differs enough that creating a config node with these additional options doesn't seem to make sense.

Obviously the token could just be provided as a text field on the test-node but the idea is to limit the amount of duplication and make the configuration more streamlined for the target users.

Using console.log(this); inside the oneditprepare() function there is a value for the token property but it is an ID which appears to point to the config node. But I can't find a way to use this to get the value of that node.

token: "5a1ab56c.5e478c"

I have tried RED.nodes.getNode() but this method is only available in the Runtime API: http://nodered.org/docs/api/runtime/api#getNode

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to implement your own communication between config dialog HTML and the nodejs code on the runtime side. The normal way to do this is to add a HTTP endpoint in the nodejs code and make AJAX style calls to this endpoint to populate the drop down.

There are some similar examples in the [node-red-nodes](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes) git repository. One example is the [WeMo node](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/tree/master/hardware/wemo).

**WeMoNG.js**

```
...
RED.httpAdmin.get('/wemoNG/devices', function(req, res) {
    res.json(wemo.devices);
});
...
```

**WeMoNG.html**

```
...
oneditprepare: function() {
    var devices;
    $.getJSON('wemoNG/devices', function(data) {
        devices = data;
        var devs = Object.keys(data);
        if (devs.length !== 0) {
            for (var d in devs) {
                if (devs.hasOwnProperty(d)) {
                    $('<option/>',{
                        'value': devs[d],
                        'text': data[devs[d]].name
                    }).appendTo('#node-config-input-device');
                }
            }
       }
    });
    $('#node-config-input-device').change(function() {
        var id = $( "#node-config-input-device option:selected" ).first().val();
        if (devices) {
            $('#node-config-input-type').val(devices[id].type);
            $('#node-config-input-name').val(devices[id].name);
        }
    });
}
...
```